# Make cannot find present cross compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I'm using a make file to compile a kernel for an arm/Xilinx platform.

I'm setting an env variable `CROSS_COMPILE` which the make file will then use.

I'm trying to use a cross compiler, which is present on my system, called `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc` by setting the env var in the following ways;

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-
```

The make file should append `gcc`.

The error given for both is

```
make: /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make: /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

It works with other arm cross compilers but this one.

Why is this?

Comment: Can you try to do `ls -l /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc` and check your chmod? If not executable, just `chmod +x /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. Do this also for the other binary files in the directory.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root is the output of ls -l, what do you think?

Comment: Maybe it's not the good binary format. Try `/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc --help` to see if you can execute it. It could be a 64bits executable on a 32bits platform. Try `file /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc` to see the file detail.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't seem to work. Also did a 777 in case it was permissions related

Comment: When I try and execute it or do a file I get the same command not found/no such file or directory]

Comment: So the toolchain you have is not for your host platform. Try to get one for your platform (do `uname -a` to see what it is).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84368/discussion-between-jml-and-mark-corrigan).

Comment: Sorry jml, I'm at work and it seems to block the chat app. My platform is x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You can check the `gcc` binary format with the `file` command: `file /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.2/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Comment: arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According answers you gave in comments, you are trying to run a 32bits executable on a 64bits host platform.

So, if your are on Ubuntu check [this answer from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/454254).